# Populate list from linq query result

Tags: c#, linq, list, dapper

I have the following code, I'm returning results that are associated with the userId, I then want to loop through the results and build a collection and return it back to the UI.

```
 public List<UserEmails> LoadUsersInbox(Int64 userId, int status)
    {
        List<UserEmails> userEmails = null;

        using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Context.ReturnDatabaseConnection()))
        {
            var emails = sqlCon.Query<UserEmailEntity>(@"SELECT e.EmailId, e.ItemId, u.Username as FromUserName, e.EmailReceived
                                                   FROM User_Emails e
                                                   INNER JOIN User_Profile u on e.FromUserId = u.UserId
                                                   WHERE ToUserId = @userId and EmailStatus = @Status",
                                                   new { ToUserId = userId, Status = status }).OrderBy(d => d.EmailReceived);

            foreach (var item in emails)
            {
                // loop through and build and List of UserEmails
            }
        }

        return userEmails;
    }
```

But I can't figure out the syntax for it, can some one help me please.

Comment: What syntax can't you figure out? Are you getting compile errors or runtime errors with what you've tried?

Comment: If the query returns correctly what you want, you can simply do OrderBy(d => d.EmailReceived).ToList() and then return emails. You don't need the foreach loop.

Comment: So is this query not compiling, or is it giving you an empty list, or is it giving you incorrect values?  As starlight54 has said (more or less), what you have showing now /is/ a collection.  That is why we are all asking for more clarification in what you need that you don't already have.

Comment: My method returns List<UserEmails> I'm currently querying the UserEmailEntity so when I say return emails it says cannot convert expression type UserEmailEntity to UserEmails that's why I asked how do I Build the List<UserEmails> from the results in emails @philologon

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the list without going to the foreach loop.  You do this with the Select statement.  I am not able to verify this (thus untested code), but it ought to work if you make do this:

```
public List<Int64> LoadUsersInbox(Int64 userId, int status)
{
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Context.ReturnDatabaseConnection()))
    {
       return sqlCon.Query<UserEmailEntity>
            (@"SELECT e.EmailId, e.ItemId, u.Username as FromUserName, e.EmailReceived
               FROM User_Emails e
               INNER JOIN User_Profile u on e.FromUserId = u.UserId
               WHERE ToUserId = @userId and EmailStatus = @Status",
               new { ToUserId = userId, Status = status })
            .OrderBy(d => d.EmailReceived)
            .Select(usrEmlEnt => usrEmlEnt.EmailId);
    }
    return new List<Int64>();
}
```

Comment: @phiologon thanks for the snippet, I get an error on .Select(usrEmlEnt => usrEmlEnt.UserEmails); which is WebServices.DatabaseEntity.UserEmailEntity' does not contain a definition for 'UserEmails' and no extension method 'UserEmails' accepting a first argument of type 'WebServices.DatabaseEntity.UserEmailEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Okay, of the four items in your SQL select statement, which one maps to UserEmails?  I.e., is it the same type as UserEmails, or does it need to be transformed (like maybe in a constructor)?

Comment: Ok, UserEmailEntity is a class which creates the table in SQL (using Entity Framework) UserEmails is a cut down version of the Entity class purely because I don't need all the properties inside UserEmailEntity now in regards to mapping I use the EmailId and UserId

Comment: Notice that in your original post, you did not put any statements in your foreach loop.  So my suggestion of what goes in the Select statement is still valid, but you are really asking what goes in that foreach loop, right?  Okay, now we need more info on the type of UserEmailEntity and UserEmails.  What are the definitions (properties only)?  We only need the pertinate properites? Is that emailID, and is that a long?  If so, then you might be able to just return an IEnumerable<Long> or <int>.

Comment: Thats correct yes, as I'm populating "emails" from the select query, then I was hoping to loop through it and build the List<UserEmails> and then return it. EmailId is a Long correct.

Comment: And you are using the Long downstream in another statement to get the email contents?  If so, you only need to return IEnumerable<Long>, which would be populated from EmailId.  Am I on track here?  I.e., you are not trying to populate your return value with all of the email contents, or not even the email Subject Line contents?

Comment: At this moment in time yes that's correct, the reason we have ItemId in the select statement is because we will be displaying the ItemDescription but i'm waiting on the DBA to complete the items table, then I'll join the table to return the Item Title, I'll be using the EmailId to return the email contents when the user clicks on it.

Comment: Stackoverflow now suggests we "automatically move this discussion to chat".  I recommend this, but it is on you to do it.  So here is my suggestion, return IEnumerable<Long>.  You can .ToList() it later if needed, but don't do that until you need it.  That way the SQL query won't be run until called for.  Then you would do something like .Select((usrEmlEnt => usrEmlEnt.EmailId);  That makes the CLR do the foreach/AddThings loop for you, but only when needed.

Comment: Momentarily I will change my answer to reflect these clarifications.